# how to get sha256 hashed string in erlang?

Tags: cryptography, erlang, sha256

I'm trying to encrypt string via sha256 in erlang, but I could not manage to get string back. crypto:hash(sha256, somestring) gives some binary, how can I get string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The binary has to be decoded to an integer, and then printed in hexadecimal form:

```
1> io_lib:format("~64.16.0b", [binary:decode_unsigned(crypto:hash(sha256,
 "somenewstring"))]).
"abf8a5e4f99c89cabb25b4bfde8a1db5478da09bcbf4f1d9cdf90b7b5321e43c"
```

`binary:decode_unsigned/1` decodes the whole binary as one large big-endian unsigned integer. An alternative would be to pattern match the binary into an integer:

```
2> <<Integer:256>> = crypto:hash(sha256, "somenewstring").
<<171,248,165,228,249,156,137,202,187,37,180,191,222,138,
  29,181,71,141,160,155,203,244,241,217,205,249,11,123,83,
  ...>>
3> Integer.
77784820141105809005227607825327585337759244421257967593474620236757179950140
4> io_lib:format("~64.16.0b", [Integer]).
"abf8a5e4f99c89cabb25b4bfde8a1db5478da09bcbf4f1d9cdf90b7b5321e43c"
```

(Note that `<<Integer:256>>` is equivalent to `<<Integer:256/big-unsigned-integer>>` since those are the default flags).

Comment: Or even easier: `L = integer_to_list(X, 16).`

Comment: @SteveVinoski: `integer_to_list(X, 16)` can accidentaly end up with shorter string.

Comment: True. but just examine the first byte in that case: `B = <<B0:8,_/binary>> = crypto:hash(sha256,"somenewstring"), <<X:256/big-unsigned-integer>> = B, L = case B0 < 10 of true -> [$0|integer_to_list(X,16)]; false -> integer_to_list(X,16) end.`

Comment: @SteveVinoski: For example `"li"` has SHA256 `00A9E4255A5B63067B76CBFB9FD67F26BDB91BE802D5FFCB177EC1B7A8D4C623` and `"efj"` has `00080A3203FE58F70B16E857765FF5C7BEAD5A9B7A9E9DD2B85ADC4CA124B9D4` and `"suo"` has `0001342CA3E5723F55ECE7107F92B39DB6B99BF0816B9509C7FD50E11A138308` and `"vkq"` has `0009E3AC3287DA952D1381A7261396404033091FFE56A0E569B9B1409CD4E5EE` and `"xym"` has `000E50E0F8CF93D9FA8C6437F681A3810F71E2B159C8E02433BEF470D45CF5AE`

Comment: Ah, good point. You can still just fill with leading zeroes, but to be fully general you need to walk the bytes until you either find one >= 16 or you find they're all 0. But at that point you're just better off with a comprehension as in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative way how to get *`sha256` hashed string* in Erlang:

```
[ element(C+1, {$0,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$A,$B,$C,$D,$E,$F}) || <<C:4>> <= crypto:hash(sha256,"somenewstring")]
```